# How to return JSONObject from doInBackground() method to onPostExecute() method on AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android

In Android app i want to return JSONObject from `doInBackground()` method to `onPostExecute()` method.
Here is the code:

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
     {
         JSONObject jsonObjRecv;
         String result;

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
        AssetObj assetObj = new AssetObj();
        assetObj.setAssetName(txtname.getText().toString());
        assetObj.setMobileNo(txtmobile.getText().toString());
        assetObj.setOwnerId(myApp.getOwnerId());
        assetObj.setStartTime(startTime.getText().toString());
        assetObj.setEndTime(endTime.getText().toString());
        assetObj.setInterval(interval.getText().toString());
        JSONObject jsonObjRecv = SyncService.AddNewAssetRequest(assetObj);
        return jsonObjRecv;
     }
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj){
                    if(obj != null)
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
```

I have try this code i got error. Is it possible to return JSONObject from `doInBackground()` method to `onPostExecute()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edited:**

This could Help you,

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONOnject>
 {
     JSONObject jsonObjRecv;
     String result;

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
    AssetObj assetObj = new AssetObj();
    assetObj.setAssetName(txtname.getText().toString());
    assetObj.setMobileNo(txtmobile.getText().toString());
    assetObj.setOwnerId(myApp.getOwnerId());
    assetObj.setStartTime(startTime.getText().toString());
    assetObj.setEndTime(endTime.getText().toString());
    assetObj.setInterval(interval.getText().toString());
    JSONObject jsonObjRecv = SyncService.AddNewAssetRequest(assetObj);
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj){
            if(obj != null)
            {
                //do something
            }
```

Here is it clearly ,

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<What type of input you need to pass to doInBackground(), Void, What type of return value you need to return to onPostExcute()>
```

Probably you dont need to change return values and params in the method declaration.

Just create the following line

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONOnject>
```

the methods will be created automatically according to the params and return types you mentioned in

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONOnject>
```

Comment: Thank you for explained about private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<What type of input you need to pass to doInBackground(), Void, What type of return value you need to return to onPostExcute()>  In AsyncTask<String, Void, String> in this you explained about First String and last String why we using, what is the purpose of middle genric type? if it has other than Void... Please explain it.....

Comment: Gud qtn dude, AsyncTask<What type of input you need to pass to doInBackground(), The progress value for updating the progress view while processing the task,What type of return value you need to return to onPostExcute()>


protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress_value) {
         setProgressPercent(progress_value[0]);
     }

Integer Value indicates the progress percentage or size or something else what we would like to show as a progress message.

You haven't implemented onProgressUpdate() method,so i don't wish to make U confused by adding Dis.So i left it.Do well Dude...

Answer (score 2):

For `AsyncTask<T1, T2, T3>` pass `T3` as `JSONObject`

Answer (score 2):

OK, Now look at this carefully,

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

In your AsyncTask third Parameter is `String` So change it to `JSONObject` .

like,

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

change to

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JsonObject>
```

The Actual Code

```
private class AddAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONOnject>
 {
     JSONObject jsonObjRecv;
     String result;

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {
    AssetObj assetObj = new AssetObj();
    assetObj.setAssetName(txtname.getText().toString());
    assetObj.setMobileNo(txtmobile.getText().toString());
    assetObj.setOwnerId(myApp.getOwnerId());
    assetObj.setStartTime(startTime.getText().toString());
    assetObj.setEndTime(endTime.getText().toString());
    assetObj.setInterval(interval.getText().toString());
    JSONObject jsonObjRecv = SyncService.AddNewAssetRequest(assetObj);
 }
 protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject obj){
            if(obj != null)
            {
                //do something
            }
}
}
```

AsyncTask < Params, Progress, Result >

1. Params, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
2. Progress, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
3. Result, the type of the result of the background computation