# Android send JSON with http get method.result is null

Tags: java, android, http, http-post, gson

I'm trying to send `JSON` with http post. I serializationed `JSON` with `GSON` and this is a my source code:

```
public void SendHttpPostRequest(final String url, final String json) {

    class HttpGetAsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Dialog pDialog;
        private String response;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CredoGenerireba.this);

            pDialog.setCancelable(false);

            pDialog.show();

            pDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_progressdialog);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse resp;

                post.setEntity(new StringEntity("{ p: " + json + " }",HTTP.UTF_8));

                // Add headers

                post.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                post.addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                // Convert Response Entity To JsonString

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                resp = httpclient.execute(post);

                HttpEntity httpEntity = resp.getEntity();
                response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                System.out.println(response  +" response");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();



            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (pDialog != null)

            {

                pDialog.dismiss();

            }

            System.out.println(result + "Result issss");

        }

    }

    HttpGetAsyncTask2 httpGetAsyncTask2 = new HttpGetAsyncTask2();

    httpGetAsyncTask2.execute();

}
```

I'm calling my asynctask function like this:

```
final Gson gson = new Gson();

myjson = gson.toJson(mainjson);
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    SendHttpPostRequest(
                            "myurl",
                            gson.toJson(mainjson));

                }
            }, 5000);
```

I logged myjson string an i revised correct result(as I would to receive) I have problem in http post method. When I try to run my program in `onPostExecute` result is null.
What is wrong I don't know if anyone knows solution please help me thanks.

Comment: null Result issss @Gauraw Yadav

Comment: Your json text is in String response; So use that in onPostExecute. Add a println() to see it.

Comment: yes i know but in onPostExecute resulit is null and server  nothink returned @greenapps

Comment: Of course result is null as doInBackground returns null. But that does not matter.  The real result is in String response. So use that. Now did you print it? Or is there an exception? Place a log statement in the catch block too.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong, you are returning "null" in doInBackground(), what you return from doInBackground is passed to onPostExecute()

to return JSONObject, check this out

[How to return JSONObject from doInBackground() method to onPostExecute() method on AsyncTask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191285/how-to-return-jsonobject-from-doinbackground-method-to-onpostexecute-method)

Also, read this article on [AsyncTask](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)

Comment: i sent json in  server,server returned  jsonobject and i  want to show result in  onPostExecute.if you know solution please help me .thanks