# Android: How to display Google Map multiple markers by fetching data from JSON

Tags: android, json, google-maps

How to display Google Map multiple markers by fetching data from JSON

Below is my Java code where I want to parse my JSON and add Google Map markers:

```
package com.rhsp.locator;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.rhsp.locator.R;

public class NearbyActivity extends Activity {
    public ArrayList<Facilities> fList;
    //  FacilitiesAdapter fadapter;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private GoogleMap maps;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby);
        setTitle("Nearby Facilities");
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LatLng HFLoc = new LatLng(-1.8691541, 30.0058391);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HFLoc, 8));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .title("Here")
        .snippet("Here")
        .position(HFLoc));
        fList = new ArrayList<Facilities>();
        new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://bclrwanda.com/health/allfa.php");

    }
    class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(NearbyActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
            dialog.setTitle("Connecting to server");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                //------------------>>
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if (status == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("allcenters");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                        Facilities centres = new Facilities();

                        centres.setFacilityName(object.getString("hcname"));
                        centres.setCatName(object.getString("catname"));
                        centres.setSector(object.getString("sector"));
                        centres.setLatitude(object.getDouble("latitude"));
                        centres.setLongitude(object.getDouble("longitude"));
                        //                      Display values
                        double lat = object.getDouble("latitude");
                        double lon = object.getDouble("longitude");
                        System.out.println("Lat: " + lat + " Lon: " + lon);
                        fList.add(centres);
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                //------------------>>  b 
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            dialog.cancel();
            //fadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            try{
                for(int i=0; i<fList.size(); i++){
                    System.out.println("Latitude: " + fList.get(i));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                System.out.println("This went wrong: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            if(result == false)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And below is my JSON that I want to use to add Google Map markers:

```
{"allcenters":[
    {
        "hcid":"13","hcname":"Kacyiru Cs",    
        "sector":"Kacyiru",
        "longitude":"30.0752",
        "latitude":"-1.9331",
        "catname":"HC"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"11",
        "hcname":"Gashora Cs",
        "sector":"Gashora",
        "longitude":"1.3263263",
        "latitude":"30.15498645",
        "catname":"HC"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"12",
        "hcname":"Juru Cs",
        "sector":"Juru",
        "longitude":"1.3263263",
        "latitude":"30.15498645",
        "catname":"HO"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"14",
        "hcname":"Kacyiru Police Hospital",
        "sector":"Kacyiru",
        "longitude":"30.075489",
        "latitude":"-1.932984",
        "catname":"HO"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"15",
        "hcname":"Kabusunzu Cs",
        "sector":"Nyakabanda",
        "longitude":"30.0519",
        "latitude":"-1.963",
        "catname":"HC"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"16",
        "hcname":"Kimironko Cs",
        "sector":"Kimironko",
        "longitude":"30.1261",
        "latitude":"-1.9514",
        "catname":"HC"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"17",
        "hcname":"Caraes Ndera",
        "sector":"Ndera",
        "longitude":"30.169",
        "latitude":"-1.9547",
        "catname":"HO"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"18",
        "hcname":"Avega Kigali Cs",
        "sector":"Remera",
        "longitude":"30.1068",
        "latitude":"-1.9585",
        "catname":"HC"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"19",
        "hcname":"Rutunga Hp",
        "sector":"Rutunga",
        "longitude":"30.1068",
        "latitude":"-1.9585",
         "catname":"HO"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"20",
        "hcname":"Butaro Hp",
        "sector":"Butaro",
        "longitude":"29.8366",
        "latitude":"-1.4089",
        "catname":"HO"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"21",
        "hcname":"Gikonko Cs",
        "sector":"Gikonko",
        "longitude":"29.8552",
        "latitude":"-2.484",
        "catname":"HC"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"22",
        "hcname":"Pharmacy Continental",
        "sector":"Kibaza",
        "longitude":"30.085321",
        "latitude":"-1.934726",
        "catname":"HO"
    },
    {
        "hcid":"23",
        "hcname":"King Faycal Hospital",
        "sector":"Kacyiru",
        "longitude":"30.0951898",
        "latitude":"-1.9439559",
        "catname":"HO"
    }
]}
```

Comment: add marker logic in for loop. what is wrong with that??

Comment: When i add maker in for loop the app crashes. I think the markers must be added in onPostExecute

Comment: Put your logic of put marker after declare lat and lon.

Answer (score 0):

Add the markers after map is ready. This can be achieved by using a onMapReady() override method.

```
     @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
       //use a for loop to process your json data here
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(yourlatitudes, yourlongitudes))
            .title("Title for marker"));
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that i cant access the content of the JSON object out of "doInBackground"

Comment: Make the json object global and try to access the same in marker method. This will solve the problem.

Comment: I found it, the only problem was the return type of doInBackground. It was Boolean and i changed to JSONObject and form there i can access the object in onPostExecute and make a loop to display all makers on the Google map. This link helped me a lot. Thank you all for your support. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191285/how-to-return-jsonobject-from-doinbackground-method-to-onpostexecute-method