# onPostExect on Android AsyncTask doesn't get called

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I've trying to create an Android client to cal via AsyncTask. Server has a primary and a secondary job to do for the same connection. If the primary returns some result then I don't need to do the secondary part but if server returns null I want to ask User using an AlertDialog if he wants to continue and if he says yes then I continue the communication with the server.

To do that I've seperated the call on doInBackground() and onPostExecute() method. Here is my logic:

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    //Do primary part of the call
    return obj;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object obj) {
    if(obj == null) {
        super.onPostExecute(obj);
        //Throw alert window to ask user if he wants to continue
        //If user says yes call server to do the the secondary part
    }
}
```

from the mainActivity when I call this AyncTask I use the get() method so that I can wait until it's inished to take the result.
My problem is that onPostExecute() never gets called...Any ideas?Does it play any role the fact that I contue calling the server on onPostExecute()?

Comment: maybe the `obj` is null, and that's why your code isn't executed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191285/how-to-return-jsonobject-from-doinbackground-method-to-onpostexecute-method

Comment: @VladMatvienko sometimes it is null and that's why I have the PostExecute to handle it..

Comment: are you sure that the `onPostExecute` is not called? Have you checked in the debugger?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya my task looks like this: extends AsyncTask<Double, Void, MyClass>. Server passes me a JSON String and I deserialize there. I don't think that the other post helps

Comment: @VladMatvienko yes

Comment: Where did you create the AsyncTask instance? Its constructor must be invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: @wrkwrk I create it on the Activity where I need it...also the entire class is written as a private class in this Activity

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE USES OF ASYNCTASK

Want to give AsyncTask a try? Here’s an example of how to use this function.

```
class DoSomeTask extends AsyncTask{

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
      //Setup precondition to execute some task 
}

@Override 
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
     //Do some task
     publishProgress (1);
     return ""; 
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) { 
     //Update the progress of current task 
}

@Override 
protected void onPostExecute(String s) { 
     //Show the result obtained from doInBackground
}
}
```

more details : https://www.upwork.com/hiring/mobile/why-you-should-use-asynctask-in-android-development/

and 

http://www.journaldev.com/9708/android-asynctask-example-tutorial

Comment: is there some magic in there that I'm supposed to understand? I have to use the onPostExecute because doInBackground isn't connected with the UI and it cant throw a dialog.

Comment: you can not called systematically, so you should read first carefully brother.

Comment: if you understand that process that how to called this, so you can implement later easily. @i_ll_be_back, best of luck!